# Create Two Column Related Thumbnails in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

[I want two column related thumbnail like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIvYe.jpg)I Want To create two-column thumbnail related posts like in screenshot I have linked to:

This is the code so far:

```
<!---Related Posts --->
<div class="singlerelated"> 
    <div class="headingbig"><div class="shortcode-unorderedlist fa fa-hand-o-right"> Lees meer over <span class="headingorange"><?php the_category(', ') ?></span></div>
</div> 
<div class="relatedentry">
<?php
$orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category)
        $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

    $args=array(
        'category__in' => $category_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=> 8,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );

    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );  

    while($my_query->have_posts()) {  
        $my_query->the_post(); 
    ?>    
    <ul>
        <li class="even">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?> title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100), array('class' => 'relatedthumb'));  ?> </a>
            <p class="title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>  
    <?
    }  
}  

$post = $orig_post;  
wp_reset_query();  
?>
    </div>  
</div>   
<!---Related Posts --->
```

I want it to be displayed in 2 columns, By Creating `li` class either even or odd generated alternatively so I can put even class in left side and other in right side. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `$i` auto-increment value in your loop. You probably want to do a `for` with a count and round up incase you have an odd number of posts. May not put an end `</ul>` on it if you don't do a count. This is the idea though:

```
$i = 1;
while($my_query->have_posts()) {  
    $my_query->the_post();
    // If $i equals 1, start the <ul>
    if($i == 1)
        echo '<ul>'.PHP_EOL; 
?>  <li class="even">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100), array('class' => 'relatedthumb'));  ?></a>
        <p class="title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </p>
    </li>
<?php
    // end on the second loop
    if($i == 2) {
        echo '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
        // Reset the count back to 0 so it starts
        // back at 1 after incrementing
        $i = 0;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

**EDIT** To do even and odd, you can use a modulus calculation:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    echo (($i % 2) == 0)? 'even:'.$i.'<br />' : 'odd: '.$i.'<br />';
```

Comment: Thank you Rasclatt , I am not that good in Coding SO can you implement this code in My Code and Post here please??

Comment: Did you try what I have first to see if it's basicially what you want?

Comment: I Dont Know Where to add this Code, But what i want to is, i want to generate <li class="even"> and <li class="odd"> alternatively

Comment: Well I took your code and just add the `$i` stuff. Look at your code where the `while` is happening and see what I did vs that.

Comment: Also, if you want to do even and odd, you can do a modulus(`%`) equation.